# java swing transparency issues under linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu, transparent

I'm having a heck of a time getting swing component transparency to work properly under Ubuntu 14.04. For example, if I employ the [SwingJD library](http://www.jroller.com/DhilshukReddy/entry/swingjd_project), the glossy buttons render properly under Windows and OSX but some (not all - I've inspected the source and can't figure out what the difference is between the ones that render correctly and the ones that fail to) don't render properly under Ubuntu 14.04. I've also tried making components like JToolBar translucent to no avail. I know there are issues with Swing and Linux where transparency is concerned, and I've already tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255218/jtoolbar-background-and-drag-problems), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886329/java-swing-jtoolbar), [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57078-make-a-transparent-swing-ui-components/), and [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1362779?start=0&tstart=0) with no luck. Has anyone found a way around this problem? I'd hate to have to create a less-asthetically-interesting UI for only Linux users.

[here's a direct link](http://jroller.com/DhilshukReddy/resource/SwingJD/sourcecode.jar) to the SwingJD source jar if you want to re-create the issue for yourself. it comes with a test class that has a main method that will render three buttons, two of which won't render correctly under Ubuntu.

EDIT>> constructors for SwingJD

"STANDARD_ORANGE_THEME" works while "STANDARD_LIGHT_ORANGE_THEME" doesn't

```
    case Theme.STANDARD_ORANGE_THEME:
        buttonColor = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(251, 139, 62), 0,
                height, new Color(255, 102, 0));
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        break;
    case Theme.STANDARD_LIGHTORANGE_THEME:
        buttonColor = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(247, 174, 24), 0,
                height, new Color(255, 133, 0));
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        break;
```

[image: screenshot displaying behaviour as well as output Kevin wanted to see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far as I can tell, the answer to my question "is there a workaround" is no. there are numerous bugs in the Java Bug Database pertaining to issues like this. [this report in particular](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6848852) states the following:

> The fix for 6794764 removed the calls to the setDoubleBiffered(false)
>   method from the Window.setLayeresOpaque() private method. Ealier the
>   double buffering was turned off for the glass pane, the root pane, and
>   the content pane when a frame went non-opaque. When double buffering
>   was enabled, the painting was performed incorrectly, thus requiring to
>   turn off the functionality. This, however, had mainly been tested on
>   MS Windows platform due to some issues with the XToolkit
>   implementation of non-opaque windows.
>
> Currently the toolkit-related issues are fixed. However, transparent
>   windows on X11 work incorrectly. If one restores the calls to the
>   setDoubleBuffered() method in the setLayeresOpaque() method, then the
>   windows start displaying OK on X11.
>
> It looks like the fix for 6683775 does not fix the double-buffering
>   issue completely.
>
> As to why this is only reproducible on X11: most probably because,
>   contrary to WToolkit, the XToolkit.needUpdateWindow() returns false.
>   This slightly changes the logic in the RepaintManager class (and,
>   maybe, some other classes in Swing), thus making the painting a bit
>   different.
>
> Since AWT does not explicitly depends on the double-buffered property
>   of components, the painting artifacts are most likely caused by the
>   Swing painting code. The bug is reassigned to Swing for further
>   evaluation.

[and this one](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6849774) which states:

> Note that until the bug 6848852 is fixed, that is unfeasible to test
>   transparency on X11 because it simply does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Not every platform supports transparency. I've been on Linux systems that simply did not support transparent windows or components. This is especially true for virtual desktops that don't have access to graphics hardware.

You might try the [isWindowTranslucencySupported()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#isWindowTranslucencySupported-java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency-) function to see for yourself whether your system supports transparency.

From [the tutorial on transparency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html):

```
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;

// Determine what the default GraphicsDevice can support.
GraphicsEnvironment ge =
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

boolean isUniformTranslucencySupported =
    gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(TRANSLUCENT);
boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported =
    gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);
boolean isShapedWindowSupported =
    gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! Some kind of transparency is clearly supported because a subset of the SwingJD GlossyButtons render perfectly fine. The only difference between the ones that do and the ones that don't is colour. For example, the orange glossy button will render, but the lime one won't. In the source the only difference are the color and alpha values being used.

Comment: Well, what values are returned for the above methods on your system? It's going to be pretty hard to help you debug without seeing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It could be that some of the components are "faking" transparency or something. But that's just a guess until we see an MCVE.

Comment: the MCVE is the jar file I linked to, is it not? did you want me to cut out a code snippet? i figured you'd rather see the code-in-context, but i can cut out the constructors for the aforementioned buttons

Comment: Did you read the link to the MCVE article? People don't want to wade through your whole project or download entire jars just to help you debug your problem. Part of the process is narrowing the problem down to a small example. This isn't just a code snippet though, as we should be able to copy and paste it and run it without any other resources. This is a pretty standard StackOverflow (and elsewhere) question prerequisite.

Comment: it's already boiled down to what's minimally required to demonstrate the issue. it's a tiny library that makes buttons. literally all you have to do is download, compile, and execute. moreover, it's hooked together in such a way that you can't really pull out a subset that's small enough to git inside the SO text field that actually shows the problem w/o you downloading that jar.  i will, however, cut-and-paste the constructors for you.

Comment: @DavidDaedalus It's up to you. I'm just trying to provide some insight into why you might not be getting more answers. You still haven't told us what your system returns for the above properties either.

Comment: sorry for the delay - i have a day job. apologies also for not answering your query about what your code generated on my laptop. i thought i'd explained in my posting that i'd already gone through the tutorials and tried the 'easy' stuff. you can see in the eclipse console all three booleans are set to 'true'. in the application view, on the right you can see three properly rendered buttons and one improperly rendered one. moreover, nothing I do to the toolbar seems to have any effect on it's transparency.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the toolbar on the right does. I'm suggesting you run the code that I posted above and print out the values of those booleans.

Comment: respectfully, please read both the question and the comments more carefully before replying. as stated in the previous comment "you can see in the eclipse console all three booleans are set to 'true'" - which I posted in response to your query about the result of my running the code you posted. moreover, as i stated in both the question and more directly in the comment "in the application view, on the right you can see three properly rendered buttons and one improperly rendered ones" - it doesn't matter what the buttons do, it matters that they aren't rendering in a consistent fashion.

Comment: I'm not asking what you've set some booleans in eclipse to. I'm asking what values were returned by Java itself when you ran the code that I posted. If that's what you're trying to tell me, then you should make it more clear than posting a screenshot of the eclipse gui builder. But I can see I'm getting nowhere, so I'll let somebody else takeover. However, without an MCVE, I doubt you'll get much of a response. Good luck.

Comment: ok, this clearly isn't a productive discussion. thanks anyway for 'trying'. I'm going to seek help elsewhere.